# Maintain O(1) in a HashTable of very large entries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash

I am writing a code to implement separate chaining while implementing hashing. My question is that when I will insert a large number of entries then there obviously will be a lot of collisions resulting in the large linked lists. How do I maintain an O(1) time in searching then? I can implement a self-balancing BST instead of the linked list. But that will also require O(log n) time.

Comment: Hash collision is the nature of hash table. There is only one way to avoid hash collision: allocate more memory.

Comment: Your hash table needs to be bigger.

Comment: _But that will also require O(log n) time_ seems to better than O(n) in case of linked lists.

Comment: Assuming that you have a good hashing function, hash tables work best when you keep the load factor (number of entries divided by number of buckets) below 75%. Some say 70%. Above that, you start getting large numbers of collisions. If your hashing function does not produce a uniform distribution (or something close), then you'll get a lot of collisions.

Comment: Just make table of enough size. For example, create hash table with size = NumKeys/2;